# How to structure versioned data in Firebase Firestore Collection?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I need to version entries to a FireStore collection, and I'm not sure the best way to structure the data so I can load back a list of the latest versions only.

Say we have a  collection of `Item`s.  Each `Item` will have it's ID, title, content and a revision number. Each revision will change the content, and bump the rev number.

What is the best way to store the revisions?

- Each revision as a brand new `Item` in the collection

  - it would have to have some link back to the parent ID
- Or an `Item` contains its own collection, `Revisions`, each with all the data

How would I get a list of `Item`s that shows ONLY the latest revision?

For option 2 I suppose you could order by `dateCreated` and `limitToFirst(1)` ?

But I would have to load the main collection, and then loop each entry and load its latest item - not the end of the word, but feels like there is a better way.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you have any thoughts on this, or any pointers?  Not finding much on the interwebs...

Comment: See my answer below on the Firebase team's position on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went with the sub collection of `Revisions`.  The main doc kept a reference to the latest / current revision.

We simplified the requirements, so we only needed top level data in the lists, not data from the revisions.

Comment: Hello @Matt Bryson, you did this using Cloud Functions or private server? if you use Cloud Functions can you share how you keep the top level synced with the latest version inside revision?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Doug Stevenson's advice from the Firebase team, he advises in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649120/how-to-create-multi-environment-dbs-with-firestore) to a StackOverflow question to create a separate project per development environment. This is what I've outlined thus far for my project.

**QA_PROJECT**

- *CONTENT_COLLECTION*

  - feeds_document
  - sources_document
- *USERS_COLLECTION*

  - userOne_document
  - userTwo_document

**PROD_PROJECT** 
(same sub-hierarchy as above)

When I'm testing out a new feature I can take a "snapshot" of the stable version using Firestore's [export/Import capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) in order to have a backup if required.