# Is it best practice to use separate GCP projects for Firestore with microservices running in the same GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-kubernetes-engine

We're building a microservices backend that will be running in GKE.

Many of these microservices will use Firestore and I'm wondering about the best practice for GCP projects in this situation.

I'd like to have one cluster/GCP project per environment (dev, staging, prod), but since Firestore doesn't support multiple instances per project, we're planning to create additional projects for each service's Firestore DB in each environment (`development-firestore-service1`, `staging-firestore-service2` etc), and put all related projects (main project with GKE cluster + Firestore projects) in a folder per environment.

As a DevOps guy I'm not too fond of this solution (cross-project IAM permissions will be a headache) and I'd like a simpler layout if possible.

I know there is scoping / namespacing at the Firestore level : is this considered sufficient isolation between "friendly" microservices (single tenant / team) and would it require significant refactoring work on our developers part ?

What is the best practice ?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. What did you end up using and how did this play out for you? The provided answers are not really answers as they talk only about the separation of dev/test/prod environments. Are IAM permissions really an issue if projects are truly isolated? But as you are, I am too concerned about the additional overhead so many projects might bring.

Comment: Just as a side note: in my case we are not talking about separating micro-services but rather "products" or "technologies". Separating services like that sounds a bit overkill to me. The granularity feels a bit too high imo.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a separate project for each environment.

If you use only the `firestore` and not the cloud functions, hosting etc. you "could" use a single project and just add more databases for each environment. But as said I would always recommend to have separate projects. Even on the last Google IO on the Firebase live QA they recommended to have multiple projects for each env.

You could create a REST API to sync data between the env. For example copy data from one to another and even users. You would need to write the code for it on your own but you would also have the control over it.

Comment: Thank you, maybe that wasn't clear enough but I do plan to have separate projects per environment. The question is about whether to further break this down into one environment for each microservice's Firestore DB, or to keep each environment's microservices data in the same DB and use scoping/namespacing between microservices.

Comment: I got that bjut it depends on what and how much they would do (would you need to sync auth data to each, create them automaticaly etc..). One limit you could hit fast is the amount of projects you can create on Firebase with a single account. You would need to request an icrease and explain why you need more. With each project more you get also more FREE tear ;) Have you considered just adding more databases in a single project for each microservice?

Comment: Adding more databases in a single project for each microservice ? I would love to do that but it's not possible with Firestore, is it ?

Comment: Not directly. Firestore can scale much better than the realtimedatase so there is no actual need for it. But you can do it virtualy like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51510038/5519300

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tarik. For a better Devops organisation and pipeline over the month and years, it's better to have fully isolated, and replicated environment.

especially when you would like to try to update K8S or to use a new AddOn. If you crash your cluster, only the dev/test cluster is down, not the prod. If you have only one, you crash all!!

however, I also saw in different company the wish to manage only one big cluster and to split it in namespace for each environment and project. The benefit is the single management of a big cluster (instead of several small cluster, very time consuming) and the cost optimization.

In fact, it's like the discussion about Monorepo or not. There isn't only one good answer, it depends on your constraints and wishes.

Comment: Thank you but that wasn't really my question : I do plan to have separate projects per environment. I'm wondering whether to have a separate Firestore project *per microservice*, or to use namespaces/scopes to separate each microservice's data from others in the same environment.

Comment: You are right, it was obvious only in my head! I recommend you to use 1 GCP project perproject/environment. Of course, only 1 Firestore for all your microservices in the same GCP project. It's up to you to choose to extract and deploy a microservice in another project for organizational or business reason.

Comment: Thank you ! So in your experience, it's easy enough for each microservice to use its own scope/namespace in Firestore, no real drawbacks to that from a dev perspective ?
I know that in theory microservices should have fully separate databases, and a Firestore project for each provides better security/isolation.
But it's also some DevOps overhead, so I was wondering if namespaces/scopes are good enough in practice.

Comment: It's not perfect, especially when you want to snapshot/restore data when you have only on Firestore instance. Security and least privilege aren't also fully respected. But it's the easiest and acceptable compare the the DevOps works to do to have 1 project per microservice.

Comment: Yes it seems each approach has pros and cons. However, in my question I assumed Firestore makes namespacing / scoping easy, but our lead dev just told me that's not really true : it's only available in Datastore mode, and you have to manage namespacing in your collections manually, including in nested levels. So they'd much rather have a separate project.
It's surprising that Firestore doesn't have good capabilities for this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still wondering about this, GCP now supports multiple Firestore databases per project. Check out the official blog post

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project